# ajax jquery unsolved

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This a question that synthesizes two questions that remain unlsoved :

I am trying to implement some ajax method to post some comments on a webpage. I use the ajax method like such :

```
<button id="my-btn">Make an Ajax request!</button>

<script >
  $('#my-btn').click(function() {
    var comment = $('#id1').val();   
    var m = {$id2};
     var data = new Array();
     data[0]= comment;
    data[1]= m;

    $.post('{$postURL}', data, function(callback_data){

    alert('hello');

    });

  });
</script>
```

where m = {$id2}; is due to a smarty variable.

The alert('hello') works, but the php code is not processed : {$postURL} requires a method comment(){$comment = $_POST[$data[0]]; $m = $_POST[$data[1]];...}. So, postURL is like : "index.php?post=comment", and the method is comment(). Of course, when I replace {$postURL} by 
"index.php?post=comment", nothing happens in the sense that I still have the alert('hello') message but the method comment() doesn't process anything. Is this method evenc called ? Or is there a wrong syntax such that $_POST[$data[0]] and $_POST[$data[1]] aren(t recognized bt the comment() method.

The way index.php works is to redirect : to a another php page, call it mypage.php where we can find the comment() method.

Moreover, something very weird : when I corrupt $.post("{$postURL}" by $.post("{$whatever}", I still have a alert('hello') message ! And weirder, when I put an alert(callback_data); inside the callback function, I get a huge alert message, which consists of my whole php code...

Best, 
Newben

Answer (score 1):

Smarty uses those curly braces so you need to pop them in using {ldelim} and {rdelim}, also you aren't sending post data as an assoc array so $_POST['comment'] etc won't be set - try this instead:

```
<script>
  $('#my-btn').click(function() {ldelim}
    var comment = $('#id1').val();   
    var m = {$id2};
    var data = {ldelim}
      comment: $('#id1').val(),
      m: {$id2}
    {rdelim};
    $.post("{$postURL}", data, function(callback_data){ldelim}
      alert('hello');
    {rdelim});
  {rdelim});
</script>
```

Comment: So now, I don't have any alert('hello') message

Comment: Sorry, I do have in fact an alert message but my bdd remains empty, but the method comment() dosen't process...

Comment: Perhaps, it will help : I put t the veery beginning of comment() method : $this->unknownPage(); and nothing happened so, it dosen't seem that this method is called. Is there a problem with $.post("url") ? I changed by {$postURL} index.php?page=agora&amp;op=comment, ant the result is the same !